# creating a library package with sub packages

Tags: python, package

trying to make a library for personal use that i want to add to over time, i do not want to have this publicly available at all.

so i have:

```
"folder i keep everything in"
>the thing i want to import that package into.py
>"package folder"
>>__init__.py
>>"sub-package folder"
>>>__init__.py
>>>module.py
```

i will be expanding this so there are multiple sub-package folders and multiple modules in each, i would like to have in the thing i want to import that package into.py

`import "package folder"`

import all the modules in "package folder" and in any "sub-package folders"

while

`import "package folder"."sub-package folder"`

would only import all modules from the sub package folder and

`import "package folder"."sub-package folder".module.py`

would only import the specific module,

is this possible? and if so, how would i do this?

i looked through other solutions and either i couldn't understand them or they were trying to do something different to me, please keep in mind i am entry level

Comment: This is done by importing packages/modules in the `__init__.py` file of the parent packages.

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__.py` in `"package folder"`, you can import all the `sub-package` modules

For example:

```
from package.sub_package1 import module1, module2
from package.sub_package2 import module3, module4
```

This way you can use 3 different way to import any particular `module`:

```
from package import module
from package.sub_package import module
import package.sub_package.module
```

Comment: I must caution against `import *` in `__init__.py`. There's potentially a mess of overridden symbols from multiple modules / packages.

Comment: i tried that and its still not working, is there some kind of character restriction on the folder names? i have an underscore in one of the folders names, if it makes any difference im using atom and a script package for atom to let me run it in there

Comment: what error are you getting? btw atom will be discontinued on Dec 15, 2022. I would suggest switching to vscode or pycharm.

Comment: the function im calling is not defined, i have the function defined in the module and can call said function in the module

Comment: did you import the function or the module? If you imported the module, you have to call `module.function` to use the function.